# JSX Unexpected token - Webpack and babel-loader

Tags: reactjs, webpack, babeljs, webpack-2, babel-loader

I'm getting JSX parse error after upgrading **webpack** from `^1.14.0` to `"^3.0.0"`

```
ERROR in ./shared/Application.js
Module parse failed: /Users/arjunkumar/Documents/Work/test/web/shared/Application.js Unexpected token (25:2)
You may need an appropriate loader to handle this file type.
```

The related code in `Application.js` looks like this

```
ReactDOM.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router routes={Routes(store)} history={history} />
  </Provider>,
  document.getElementById('app-shell') 
);
```

Relevant part of `webpack.config.js` file looks as follows *(all the required plugins are imported properly to webpack config file, not present in the following code)*.

```
module.exports = {
  entry: {
    app:['./shared/Application.js'],
    vendors:[// vendors like react and other libs ]
  },
  output: {
    path: __dirname + '/public/build',
    filename: 'app.[chunkhash].js'
  },
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
  },
  module: {
    rules: [
      {
        test: /\.scss$/,
        loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
          fallback: 'style-loader',
          use: [
            'css-loader',
            'autoprefixer-loader',
            'sass-loader'
          ],
          exclude: /node_modules/
        }),
      },
      {
        test: /\.js$/,
        exclude: [/node_modules/],
        use:[{
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: [
              ['es2015', {modules: false}],
              'react'
            ],
            babelrc: false
          }
        }]
      },
      {
        test: /\.jsx$/,
        exclude: [/node_modules/],
        use:[{
          loader: 'babel-loader',
          options: {
            presets: [
              'es2015',
              'react'
            ],
            babelrc: false
          }
        }]
      },
    ]
  },
  devtool: ( process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' ) ? false : 'eval',
  plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin(
      'app.[chunkhash].css',
      {
        allChunks: true
      }
    ),
    new webpack.optimize.CommonsChunkPlugin({
      names: ['utilities','vendors'],
      filename: '[name].[chunkhash].js',
      minChunks: Infinity
    }),
    new webpack.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
      compressor: {
        warnings: false
      },
      output: {
        comments:false
      },
      comments: false
    }),
    new AssetsPlugin({
      filename: 'assets.json',
      fullPath: false,
      path: __dirname + '/public/build',
      prettyPrint: true
    })
  ]

};
```

Relevant dependencies for the issue from `package.json` file is as follows.

```
{
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel": "^6.23.0",
    "babel-core": "^6.25.0",
    "babel-loader": "^7.1.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-object-assign": "^6.8.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-react-constant-elements": "^6.9.1",
    "babel-plugin-transform-react-inline-elements": "^6.8.0",
    "babel-plugin-transform-react-remove-prop-types": "^0.2.9",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-es2015-loose": "^8.0.0",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-preset-stage-0": "^6.24.1",
    "babel-register": "^6.24.1",
    "extract-text-webpack-plugin": "^2.1.2",
    "html-webpack-plugin": "^2.21.0",
    "husky": "^0.13.1",
    "lodash-webpack-plugin": "^0.10.6",
    "node-sass": "^3.13.1",
    "postcss-loader": "^2.0.6",
    "purifycss-webpack": "^0.4.2",
    "sass-loader": "^4.1.1",
    "webpack": "^3.0.0",
    "webpack-bundle-analyzer": "^2.3.0",
    "webpack-dev-server": "^2.5.0"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.1.0"
  }
}
```

Just in case anyone wants to check `.babelrc` file *( I think `babel-loader` respects `babelrc: false` flag in `webpack.config.js`)*.

```
{
  "presets": [
    "es2015",
    "react",
    "stage-0"
  ],
  "env": {
    "production": {
      "plugins": [
        "transform-react-constant-elements",
        "transform-react-inline-elements",
        "transform-react-remove-prop-types"
      ]
    }
  },
  "comments": false,
  "compact": false
}
```

Any thoughts or leads on what might be wrong?

**Another important thing I noticed is even though my webpack project and global dependency is at `3.0.0`, when I run the webpack in the project it shows `Version: webpack 1.15.0` at the top. Screenshot below.**

[image: webpack wrong version]

Comment: Maybe a silly thing but, have you tried with renaming the file into `Application.jsx` instead?

Comment: @Francisco I haven't tried - though that's out of scope for the project as I've ~500 small components with file extension `.js`

Comment: @Francisco I tried that and the same thing happens

Answer (score 1):

You're running `webpack` from the command line, which means that you're running the globally installed unless you have `./node_modules/.bin/` in your `PATH`. Even though you say your globally installed version should be `3.0.0`, it is a much better idea to always run the locally installed one. If you want to run it from the command line you can do it by running:

```
./node_modules/.bin/webpack --progress
```

A more elegant way to run it, is by creating an [npm script](https://docs.npmjs.com/misc/scripts) in your `package.json`.

```
"scripts": {
  "build": "webpack --progress"
}
```

npm will automatically look into `./node_modules/.bin/` for an executable. And then you can run that script with:

```
npm run build
```

Your config looks okay, except for `resolve.extensions`, which no longer allows/requires an empty string.

```
resolve: {
  extensions: ['.js', '.jsx']
},
```

I don't really see why you're using two different rules for `.js` and `.jsx`. You can have a regular expression that matches both with `/\.jsx?$/`. But the two rules are not identical. The difference is that you use `modules: false` only for `.js`, but you should let webpack handle the ES modules. If you don't have a reason to do it differently, you should combine the two rules.

Comment: Thanks Michael, I did try after removing the empty string in `resolve.extensions`, but no luck. Regarding the local webpack, I also have a npm run build script which executes `cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack -p --progress --colors` - no luck here either.

Comment: No luck as in the output is exactly the same, with `1.x` showing in the output?

Comment: Does that still say version `1.15.0`? If that's the case, you could try to delete `node_modules` and re-install them, because it works just fine with the `package.json` you posted.

Comment: @loganfsmyth yes. And global webpack is 3.0.0 only (from  `npm list -g --depth=0` ). https://screencast.com/t/r1ieA98RG

Comment: @MichaelJungo I deleted the node_modules and cleaned NPM cache. Later I upgraded NPM to latest ( 5.1.0 ) also

Comment: Do you have a `package-lock.json`? I've heard people were having issues with npm5's lock file. If you do, you should delete that and re-install again.

Answer (score 0):

If it says `Webpack 1.x` in the output when you compile, then that is why it isn't working. Your config is for Webpack 3, so Webpack 1 doesn't know what to do with it.

This is likely because you've installed `webpack@1.x` as a global module, e.g. `npm i webpack -g` which means the version of it is unrelated to the version in your `package.json`. Installing dependencies globally is generally not a good idea because of this type of issues unless you are installing a truly global application from npm.

The first step would be to `npm uninstall -g webpack` so you don't accidentally run the global version anymore, then you need to explicitly run your local version when building, e.g.

instead of just running

```
webpack
```

you should run

```
$(npm bin)/webpack
```

so that you run the version of Webpack installed into `node_modules`.

Comment: When I upgraded my project webpack to 3.x.x I uninstalled and installed 3.x globally as well. And I tried to run webpack from `package.json` also

Comment: If you uninstall the global one, does it still run? Maybe you have two global copies in your PATH somewhere. If the output says 1.x like you said, there must be a 1.x version somewhere.

Comment: any suggestions on how I can make sure that 1.x package is not in global PATH somewhere?

Comment: Run `which webpack` and figure out where the `1.x` version is on your system. What is your Node setup? Do you use a global Node, or do you use `nvm`?

Comment: `which webpack` returns just `/usr/local/bin/webpack` I've global node `v7.7.2` and npm `5.1.0`

Comment: That means your global install is still there. It must not have uninstalled properly.